# Having multiple measurements of position (from different sensors) for a localisation Kalman Filter

Tags: robotics, kalman-filter, control-theory

I'm trying to use a kalman filter to estimate the position of a small robot in one dimension. However, I have two sensors giving position measurement. The state I'm using is one dimensional position and velocity, but I have three measurements total for the measurement equation (two different sensors giving position, and one giving velocity). How do I combine the two different readings of position?

I tried adding an extra row to the H matrix in the measurement equation, Y = Hx. But this gives Y as a column matrix with length 3. However, the state, x, is a column matrix with length 2. This means when I try to calculate an estimate for the next state  X = X + K(Y - HX), the matrices are not matching size.

Has anyone had experience with this before? Any help / pointers would be much appreciated.